# Corda V3 - Driver tests with vaultQueryBy fail to retrieve data from vault most of the time

Tags: corda

The vaultQueryBy inside a driver closure fails to see the data as the result of the flow ahead of it. The query would return an empty set.  That happens most of the time, even though sometimes, the query returns the expected record. Why is the behavior so random?

That is only for V3.  V2 has no such a problem.

\Sean

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a race condition. There are two possibilities:

**1. You are not waiting for the future returned by the flow to resolve:**

Suppose I write the following driver code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user = User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL"))
    driver(DriverParameters(isDebug = true)) {
        val (partyA, partyB) = listOf(
            startNode(providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"), rpcUsers = listOf(user)),
            startNode(providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyB", "New York", "US"), rpcUsers = listOf(user))).map { it.getOrThrow() }

        partyA.rpc.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.Initiator::class.java, 99, partyB.nodeInfo.legalIdentities.first())
        println(partyA.rpc.vaultQuery(IOUState::class.java).states)

        Thread.sleep(10000)

        println(partyA.rpc.vaultQuery(IOUState::class.java).states)
    }
}
```

The first `println` will print an empty array, since the flow has not completed yet. Only the second `println` will return a result.

You can solve this by waiting for the flow to return before moving on, by writing:

```
partyA.rpc.startFlowDynamic(
    ExampleFlow.Initiator::class.java, 
    99, 
    partyB.nodeInfo.legalIdentities.first()
).returnValue.get()
```

**2. You query the vault before the counterparties have finished recording the transaction:**

Suppose I write the following driver code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user = User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL"))
    driver(DriverParameters(isDebug = true)) {
        val (partyA, partyB) = listOf(
            startNode(providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"), rpcUsers = listOf(user)),
            startNode(providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyB", "New York", "US"), rpcUsers = listOf(user))).map { it.getOrThrow() }

        partyA.rpc.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.Initiator::class.java, 99, partyB.nodeInfo.legalIdentities.first()).returnValue.get()
        println(partyB.rpc.vaultQuery(IOUState::class.java).states)
    }
}
```

This code is subtly different to the first iteration, in that we are calling the flow on Party A, but checking the vault of Party B. It's possible that by the time the vault is queried, the flow has finished running on Party A's node, but Party B's node is still in the process of storing the transaction's states in its vault.